# Use Sum on extra aggregation and Make Total

Tags: sql-server, sum, indexed-view

I want to create an indexed View.

I have this query:

```
SELECT srvmn.BBC_ID AS Inventory,
       srvInv.ObjectID,
       srv.State,
       SUM(  IIF(srvInv.Direction = srvInv.ReverseBroken, 1, 0)) AS Broken,
       SUM(IIF(srvInv.Direction = 0, 1, -1)) AS Sum,
       COUNT_BIG(*) AS CountLines
FROM table1 srvmn
    JOIN table2 srv
        ON srv.ServiceManID = srvmn.ID
    JOIN table3 srvInv
        ON srv.ID = srvInv.ServiceID
WHERE srv.State > 321
      AND srv.State <> 123
GROUP BY srvInv.ObjectID,
         srv.State,
         srvInv.Direction,
         srvInv.ReverseBroken,
         srvmn.BBC_ID
         ORDER BY srvInv.ObjectID
```

So, the Sum is not working properly also I fix it with this approach:

```
SELECT A.Inventory,
   A.ObjectID,
   A.State,
   A.Broken,
   SUM(A.Sum) AS Sum
FROM
(
    SELECT srvmn.BBC_ID AS Inventory,
           srvInv.ObjectID,
           srv.State,
           IIF(srvInv.Direction = srvInv.ReverseBroken, 1, 0) AS Broken,
           SUM(IIF(srvInv.Direction = 0, 1, -1)) AS Sum,
           COUNT_BIG(*) AS CountLines
    FROM table1 srvmn
        JOIN table2 srv
            ON srv.ServiceManID = srvmn.ID
        JOIN table3 srvInv
            ON srv.ID = srvInv.ServiceID
    WHERE srv.State > 321
          AND srv.State <> 123 
    GROUP BY srvInv.ObjectID,
             srv.State,
             srvInv.Direction,
             srvInv.ReverseBroken,
             srvmn.BBC_ID
) AS A
GROUP BY A.Inventory,
         A.ObjectID,
         A.State,
         A.Broken;
```

Result is OK, but Derived Tables are not allowed in Indexed Views.
I try to using "Over Partition" in Sum, but the result is not OK.

How I can fix this issue?

Correct Result :

```
Inventory   ObjectID    State   Broken  Sum
------------------------------------------------
NULL        2           500     0       -1
NULL        3           320     1       1
NULL        3           500     0       2
NULL        3           600     0       1
NULL        18          600     0       -1
NULL        20          600     0       -1
1162        20          600     0       1
NULL        24          600     0       1
NULL        26          310     0       -3
NULL        26          320     0       -1
NULL        26          600     0       7
442         26          500     0       8
442         26          500     1       1
442         26          600     0       -5
1162        26          600     0       0
NULL        27          500     0       4
NULL        27          600     0       2
1162        27          600     0       1
1162        28          600     0       3
```

Not Ok Result:

```
Inventory   ObjectID    State   Broken  Sum     CountLines
-------------------------------------------------------------
NULL        2           500     0       -1      1
NULL        3           500     0       2       2
NULL        3           600     0       1       1
NULL        18          600     0       -1      1
1162        20          600     0       3       3
1162        20          600     0       -2      2
NULL        20          600     0       1       1
NULL        20          600     0       -2      2
NULL        24          600     0       -1      1
NULL        24          600     0       2       2
442         26          600     0       -7      7
NULL        26          600     0       -18     18
1162        26          600     0       1       1
NULL        26          600     0       25      25
442         26          500     1       1       1
442         26          600     0       2       2
1162        26          600     0       -1      1
442         26          500     0       8       8
NULL        27          600     0       -3      3
1162        27          600     0       1       1
```

Comment: Can you please add some sample data with your expected output?

Comment: @mkRabbani
I add 2 results  , look at Inventory 1162
in ok result we have : 1162    20  600 0   1
but in second result we have :
1162    20  600 0   3   3
1162    20  600 0   -2  2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try it :

```
SELECT 
        srvmn.BBC_ID AS Inventory,
        srvInv.ObjectID,
        srv.State,
        SUM(IIF(srvInv.Direction = srvInv.ReverseBroken, 1, 0)) AS Broken,
        SUM(IIF(srvInv.Direction = 0, 1, -1)) AS Sum
    FROM table1 srvmn
    JOIN table2 srv     ON srv.ServiceManID = srvmn.ID
    JOIN table3 srvInv  ON srv.ID = srvInv.ServiceID
        WHERE srv.State > 321 AND srv.State <> 123
            GROUP BY 
                srvInv.ObjectID,
                srv.State,
                srvInv.ReverseBroken,
                srvmn.BBC_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use Field "srvInv.Direction" in "Group By"